# DirectCast() function to convert a variable or expression from one type to another

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim A As String = "53.3"
Dim B As Double
B = DirectCast(A, Double) / 1.14
```

I get a message

> string can't convert to Double

Answer (score 3):

The `DirectCast` operator performs an actual cast, not a conversion.  That means that it doesn't create an object of a different type but simply creates a reference of a different type to the same object.  That means that the object you refer to must already be the type that you're casting it as, e.g.

```
Dim obj As Object = 53.3
Dim dbl As Double = DirectCast(obj, Double)
```

In that case, the object being cast is already a `Double` but is referred to by a variable of type `Object`, so a cast is valid.

In your case, the object is a `String`, not a `Double`, so it cannot be cast as type `Double`.  You want to convert from `String` to `Double` so you must use a method or operator that performs a conversion.  That could be `CType` or, when converting to `Double`, `CDbl` for short.

```
Dim A As String = "53.3"
Dim B As Double
B = CDbl(A) / 1.14
```

Note that the term "cast" is used in the same way as in the expression "to cast something in a different light".  That expression means to make the same thing look different and that's exactly what casting in programming does.  It doesn't change the object you're referring to but only how you're referring to it, i.e. it creates a reference of a different type to access the same object.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it answers your question.